# Cron mail notification

Tags: notification, mail, crontab

I would like to disable crontab mail notification for one of my task...

I run this task every minute, that means 1440 mail per day :S

Can someone tell me if this is possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to make sure that your task does not produce any output.

If it is a single command add ">/dev/null 2>&1" (without the quotes) to your command.

Comment: Or if the application behaves properly and only writes to stderr when there is a real error, you can use ">/dev/null" to get mailed in case of errors only.  (Unfortunately, many applications write lots of irrelevant stuff to stderr...)